# добавить дополнительное значение при условии в таблицу

Tags: python, python-3.x

формирую html таблицу из питона

```
in_dict= {'1.7': [85], '2.7': [37, 25], '6.7': [150]}

tbl_fmt = '''
<table>
<tr>
 {}
</tr>
<tr>
 {}
</tr>
</table>'''

row_fmt  = '''
<td>{}</td>
'''

def dict_to_html_table(in_dict):
    return tbl_fmt.format(''.join([row_fmt.format(k) for k,v in in_dict.items()]),''.join([row_fmt.format(sum(v)) for k,v in in_dict.items()]))
```

таблица формируется и получаю то что мне нужно. Интересует как в тег `<td>` еще вписать что-то вроде `class='bad'` если значение `sum(v)<100`.

Comment: Добавьте пример данных

Comment: @gil9red добавил словарь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал пример с генератором шаблонов `jinja2`:

```
# pip install jinja2
import jinja2


template = jinja2.Template("""\
<table>
  <tr>
  {% for x in rows_1 %}
    <td>{{ x }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  <tr>
  {% for x in rows_2 %}
    <td {% if x < 100 %}class="bad"{% endif %}>{{ x }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</table>
""")


in_dict = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [3, 4, 5],
    'c': [99, 3],
}

html = template.render(
    rows_1=[k for k, v in in_dict.items()],
    rows_2=[sum(v) for k, v in in_dict.items()]
)
print(html)
```

Результат:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  
    <td>a</td>
  
    <td>b</td>
  
    <td>c</td>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
  
    <td class="bad">6</td>
  
    <td class="bad">12</td>
  
    <td >102</td>
  
  </tr>
</table>
```